# Specifying fill color in ggplot is changing other attributes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting the following dummy dataset

```
X<-c(1,3,5,6,7,2,1,8,8)
Y<-c(2,3,1,6,4,5,3,3,4)
Date<-c('2005','2006','2007','2005','2006','2007','2005','2006','2007')
Size<-c(20,30,40,20,10,40,20,19,15)
Group<-c("North","North","North","East","East","East","West","West","West")

DF<-data.frame(X,Y,Date,Size,Group)
```

I would like to create a bubble plot using ggplot with the following code:

```
ggplot(DF,aes(x=X, y=Y, size=Size, label=Date,fill=Group),legend=FALSE)+
geom_path(size=0.3,aes(colour=Group))+
geom_point( color='black', shape=21,alpha=0.5)+
geom_text(size=2)+
ggtitle("My Title")+
theme_bw()+
scale_size(range = c(5, 20),name="Legend Title")+
#scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette)
theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
axis.text.x=element_blank(),
legend.key=element_rect(colour='black',size=1),#Increase thickness of legend border
legend.text=element_text(size=10, face='bold'),
legend.title=element_text(size=12,face='bold'),
axis.text.y=element_blank(),
axis.title.x=element_blank(),
axis.title.y=element_blank(),
axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
axis.ticks.y=element_blank())+
guides(size=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill='black')),color=guide_legend(overide.aes=list(alpha=0.9)))#last bit colors in circles in legend
```

The above code works fine. It creates a bubble plot with the following features:

```
-Bubble fill and path color coded by group
-Corresponding legend with correct colors for both fill and lines
-Bubble legend with grey shaded in color
-Preserves all the formatting options specified in above code
```

But if want to specify the fill and line colors to make a more color blind friendly palette

```
# CB palette with grey:
cbPalette <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")
```

If I then remove the hashtag from the above plotting code to include the manual color scheme, I get a conflict that not only causes a mismatch between the fill and path, but removes the shading from my legend as well as much of the plot formatting (brings back axis labels, tic marks, and background grid).

I understand that I need to specify the path color just as I did the fill color (just not sure the best way to do that), but I don't understand why I am canceling much of the general theme formats in the plot as well as the legend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to add a `scale_colour_manual` to get the match between the path and the fill. I've changed the palette to make it easier to see what's happening. Only the first three colors of your palette are used, because there are only three levels of `Group`. Your `theme` formatting went away because there's no `+` after the `scale_fill_manual()` line, so the theme statements weren't included in the graph once you uncommented that line.

```
  cbPalette1 <- c("yellow", "pink", "green", "black", "red", "blue", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

  ggplot(DF,aes(x=X, y=Y, size=Size, label=Date,fill=Group),legend=FALSE)+
  geom_path(size=0.3,aes(colour=Group))+
  geom_point( color='black', shape=21,alpha=0.5)+
  geom_text(size=2)+
  ggtitle("My Title")+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_size(range = c(5, 20),name="Legend Title")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette1) +  
  scale_colour_manual(values=cbPalette1) +  # I ADDED THIS LINE
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        legend.key=element_rect(colour='black',size=1),#Increase thickness of legend border
        legend.text=element_text(size=10, face='bold'),
        legend.title=element_text(size=12,face='bold'),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())+
  guides(size=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill='black')),
         color=guide_legend(overide.aes=list(alpha=0.9)))#last bit colors in circles in legend
```

Note also that even though you've specified `fill='black'` inside `override.aes`, the bubbles in your legend are gray because you specified `alpha=0.5` inside `geom_point`. To get black legend bubbles, add `alpha=1` inside `override.aes`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, I thought it was something much more insidious, but it looks like it was just a simple overlook on my part. Thanks for the excellent answer.

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to be of help.